# logger.info not working in Django logging

Tags: python, logging, django-logging

Following is the logging snippet I have used in my django **settings.py** file. All the GET,POST requests are getting written to log but when i wrote **logger.info("print something"), its not getting printed/captured in console as well as the log file**

Please suggest a workaround to capture **logger.info()** logs

**views.py**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def custom_data_generator(request):
    logger.info("print somethig") # NOT GETTING CAPTURED IN LOG FILE
    return somethig
```

---

**settings.py** (**DEBUG = True** and **DEBUG_MODE = False** in settings.py file)

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s|%(name)s|%(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'applogfile': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': '/home/mahesh/Documents/refactor/unityapp/unity/media/myproject.log',
        'backupCount': 10,
        'formatter': 'simple',
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['applogfile', 'console'],
        'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
    }
}
}
```

**log data generated as follows**

```
[2020-07-07 11:43:25] ERROR|django.server|"GET /a11y/project-dashboard/?

refnum=ACGLOBAL&env_id=4 HTTP/1.1" 500 92016
[2020-07-07 12:05:21] INFO|django.server|"GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 59501
[2020-07-07 12:05:21] INFO|django.server|"GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 59501
[2020-07-07 12:05:21] INFO|django.server|"GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[2020-07-07 12:05:21] INFO|django.server|"GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
[2020-07-07 12:05:21] INFO|django.server|"GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[2020-07-07 12:05:26] INFO|django.server|"GET /admin/accessibility/axe_json/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1886434
[2020-07-07 12:05:27] INFO|django.server|"GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
[2020-07-07 12:05:27] INFO|django.server|"GET /static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 280364
[2020-07-07 12:05:27] INFO|django.server|"GET /static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js HTTP/1.1" 200 128820
[2020-07-07 12:05:34] INFO|django.server|"GET /admin/accessibility/axe_json/?page_id=https%3A%2F%2Fjobs.chegg.com%2Fapplythankyou HTTP/1.1" 200 1868950
[2020-07-07 12:05:35] INFO|django.server|"GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because your views module doesn't have a logging level set, so it will inherit the root logger's default level of `WARNING`. If you add a `root` entry with a level of `INFO`, similarly to the [documented examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#examples), you should see messages from other modules. Alternatively you can specify logger names under the `loggers` key for your specific module hierarchy, whatever that is. (Your example only overrides the `WARNING` level for modules in the `django` hierarchy, i.e. code in Django itself.)

Comment: After doing above step, every log is being captured twice in my log file. Can you please tell where am i doing wrong? here is the logging snippet
https://slack-files.com/T04MYU6C6-F0176Q8PJEQ-30938e3c8b

Comment: @Mahesh it's because you've added a handler in two places. You can remove the `applogfile` handler from the `django` logger. The handler added in the root logger is also used by the `django` logger automatically.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you provided, you are only setting the log level for the 'django' logger. That logger controls the log level for `django.request`, `django.server`, `django.template`etc. If you are looking to set the log level for your own apps, you need to set the log level for that particular app's logger, or set it for all apps using a configuration like below

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # More info on '' (unnamed) loggers at the end of this comment
        '': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console_handler'],
        },
    },

}
```

The `''` (unnamed) logger will process records from all loggers. More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/logging/#configure-a-logger-mapping

Comment: If setting an unnamed logger also does not work (no logs in console or file), what else can be done to fix this?  How does one debug the case where Django apparently ignores settings or seems to simply "fail silently"?